# iPhone accelerometer in web applications

Tags: iphone

I want my website to change its layout according to the device positon. The site has 2 layout types: vertical(height > width) ang horizontal(width > height).

do you see any solution?

**upd**: I don't see any complexity in changing the site layout. I want to know is there any event to handle.
p.s. will iphone's browser change its orientation if i rotate the device 90 degree?
Dave, tnx for emendation.

Comment: For the record, it's an accelerometer (that measures where gravity is relative to the phone), not a gyroscope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a javascript event called `onorientationchange` sent when the orientation changes and also there is a property called `orientation` on the `window` object that tells what the current orientation is.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/webapps/docs/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/chapter_7_section_9.html) for more info and sample.