# Is it possible for a web app to gather an iPhone's accelerometer data? If so, how?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, accelerometer, uiaccelerometer

Is it possible for a web app to gather an iPhone's accelerometer data? If so, how? I would think they might have in the Safari Web browser an API with such functionality.

If it is possible could someone send me a link to pages with specific coding information.

Comment: Check this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433543/iphone-accelerometer-in-web-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this snippet from [here](http://www.peterfriese.de/how-to-use-the-gyroscope-of-your-iphone-in-a-mobile-web-app/) with a bit of Googling.

```
window.ondevicemotion = function(event) {
  ax = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x
  ay = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y
  az = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z
  rotation = event.rotationRate;
  if (rotation != null) {
    arAlpha = Math.round(rotation.alpha);
    arBeta = Math.round(rotation.beta);
    arGamma = Math.round(rotation.gamma);
  }
}
```

Comment: What language is that? Javascript?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not aware of Safari supporting any other scripting language.